# Can I change the default password profile in KeePass?

Tags: keepass

I'd like my default to be 256-bit hex key. Is there a way to configure KeePass with this default?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Go to Tools / Generate Password
2. On the Settings tab, select the profile named "256-bit Hex Key"
3. Click the save button to the right of the profile name
4. It will ask for the name of the profile to save to, select "(Automatically generated passwords for new entries)" and click OK
5. Click OK again and try it!

(Using version 2.26, in case it's different in different versions)

Comment: Thanks, was fumbling with that one and with one trip to Stack Overflow, Solved!

Comment: This is not working for me: KeePass is always selecting `Derive from previous password` profile every time I create a new entry

Comment: @Jérôme Mével : I have the same behavior but I get the right pattern for password creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, selecting "Automatically generated passwords for new entries" in the dropdown menu was the task I failed at