# KeePass default password for new entries?

Tags: keepass

I am NOT meaning changing [default password profile](https://superuser.com/questions/379823/can-i-change-the-default-password-profile-in-keepass), I mean particularly setting default set of characters as password, for example setting "foobar" auto-filling for new entries.

Yes, I know it is discouraged and is not available with standard functionality, was anybody able to achieve that any way?

I tried patterns but they only specify characters sets as sources for generating password character sequence and don't allow specify sequence literally. Placeholders?

Any other standard workarounds besides using templating plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. The syntax for putting literal password is:

```
\f\o\o\b\a\r
```

One should put this pattern into **Tools->Password generation->Generate using pattern** and save as *(Automatically generated passwords for new entries)*.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

## Install keyboard shortcut software instead

Rather than tamper with or re-write a piece of security software:

Wouldn’t it be simpler to install an app that replaces a key press, or key phrase, with the phrase of your choice?   (Also known as key phrase, text replacement or shortcut software).

Press something like `alt`-`shift`-`7`, and, bang, the phrase of your choice is typed every time.

No need to modify any source code. No worry that your modifications to security software corrupt your vault or make it fail to save.  No need to perform the modification again when they update the software next month.

Comment: Thanks, will consider this as an option